# Feedback when upvoting in unregistered accounts

Tags: discussion

When you try to vote on a question on any of the stack-exchange sites, when not logged in, it shows :

> Sending feedback

What does it actually send? to whom? and how are these feedback's useful to the site?

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, the information is recorded, but not used for anything.

Comment: Doesn't it say "Thanks for the feedback!"?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, of course it does.

Comment: @Servy what is the purpose of recording information and not using them at all.

Comment: @user689 So that you can use it at some later point in time when you come up with a good way of using it.

Comment: It is stored and you can check [Feedback](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts) against posts for a particular user ID